# Centering content in cells adjacent to Sideways Headings

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, rotating

I have a table produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Item    &   Task    & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Resident Engineer \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Pavement Engineer \,
\end{sideways}} &

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Surveyor \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Environmental Specialist \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Materials Technicians \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Inspectors of Works \,
\end{sideways}} \\
\hline
Task 1  &   Mobilization and Project Inception & P  & P & P &  P    & P & P     \\
\hline
Task 2  &   Carry out data collection \& review of existing data  & P& S    & P &P  &P  & P\\
\hline
Task 3  &   Compiling and submitting the Inception report  &P   &   S&  &   &P  &       \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that **Item** and **Task** cells are not centered. How can I center the text in these two cells (vertical and horizontal alignment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the contents of the "longest" entries, you can use this to your advantage and raise the contents of the first two heading entries accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \newlength{\tabheadheight}
  \settoheight{\tabheadheight}{\rotatebox{90}{Environmental Specialist\,}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\tabheadheight-.5\normalbaselineskip}{Item} &
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\tabheadheight-.5\normalbaselineskip}{Task} & 
    \rotatebox{90}{Resident Engineer} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Pavement Engineer} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Surveyor} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Environmental Specialist\,} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Materials Technicians} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Inspectors of Works} \\
    \hline
    Task 1  &   Mobilization and Project Inception & P  & P & P &  P    & P & P     \\
    \hline
    Task 2  &   Carry out data collection \& review of existing data  & P& S    & P &P  &P  & P\\
    \hline
    Task 3  &   Compiling and submitting the Inception report  &P   &   S&  &   &P  &       \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The use of [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is sufficient to obtain rotated headings via `\rotatebox{90}{<stuff>}`. Also, using the `center` environment to centre a `tabularx` of width `\textwidth` is not necessary, since it fits to the text block width.

In the above example, the length `\tabheadheight` is used to capture the height of the "longest" entry. Subsequently, the first two headings are raised by `.5\tabheadheight-.5\normalbaselineskip`, setting them vertically centred.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner for the elegant solution and detailed explanation of how it works. I especially like the use of the `graphicx` package to obtain rotated headings, it is less cumbersome than what I used.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can override the column alignment to center, and then raise the text by eye (or you could measure the longest heading)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\raisebox{4em}{Item}}  &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\raisebox{4em}{Task}}   & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Resident Engineer \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Pavement Engineer \,
\end{sideways}} &

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Surveyor \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Environmental Specialist \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Materials Technicians \,
\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
\begin{sideways}
Inspectors of Works \,
\end{sideways}} \\
\hline
Task 1  &   Mobilization and Project Inception & P  & P & P &  P    & P & P     \\
\hline
Task 2  &   Carry out data collection \& review of existing data  & P& S    & P &P  &P  & P\\
\hline
Task 3  &   Compiling and submitting the Inception report  &P   &   S&  &   &P  &       \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```