# sideways column type based on column type c

Tags: tables, rotating

I'm trying to create a sideways column type based on column type c. At the moment it looks like this: [image: graphical example]

I want to put the expression "long word" in the vertical middle of the column and remove the error droping my text text text ... field. I searched and tried but I didn't succed.

This is my minmal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{sideways}}c<{\end{sideways}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R|X|}
\hline
\rotatebox{270}{1234} & text\\
\hline
long word & text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [Centering content in cells adjacent to Sideways Headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49420/5764); [Text gets out beyond the table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83400/5764); [How to make TeX fit rotated text into table cell?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74546/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you can do here to get the effect you want.

The first is to redefine `\tabularxcolumn`.  When you call the `X` column type, `tabularx` converts the column into a type `p{...}` column.  You can change this behavior.

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
```

to get a `parbox` that will be centered.
Please see the documentation for `tabularx` for further details.

The second is not to use the `rotating` package, but to use `graphicx` package's potential to define the point about which the rotation occurs.  The unfortunate drawback of this is that `graphicx` does not provide the `sideways` environment you use.  So, to this end, you'll define a new `sideways` environment.

Here's a MWE which illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%--------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\ingo@sideways@box}
\newenvironment{ingosideways}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\ingo@sideways@box}}
  {\end{lrbox}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\usebox{\ingo@sideways@box}}}
\makeatother
%%--------------------
%%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{ingosideways}}c<{\end{ingosideways}}}
%%--------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| R | X |}\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{1234}             & text                         \\\hline
{This is a very long entry for this column} & {\let\par\relax\lipsum[1-2]} \\\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've enclosed the redefining of `\tabularxcolumn` within a group so that the redefinition does not adversely effect the use of `tabularx` environments later in your document.

Also, the use of `lipsum` here creates some *erroneous* white space making the centering look unbalanced:  to *correct* this I've also temporarily redefined `\par` within the scope of where I'm calling `lipsum`.  In your own document, you should not need this correction!

Comment: The second solution just works fine for me.
Thank you a lot!
And as you predicted I didn't have to use `lipsum`

Answer (score 2):

If `tabularx` is not a must, I'd suggest the package `cals`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1.1cm}{12cm}}
\brow
\alignC\cell{1234}
\alignL\cell{text}
\erow
\brow
\alignC\cell{\vfil\begin{sideways}long word\end{sideways}}
\alignL\cell{\lipsum[1-2]}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually tabularx is a must.